# From a string without length constraint, How to generate multiple random strings with length constraint?

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, hash, distributed-system

In a java based distributed system, I need to create multiple random (as many as possible) strings {x_i}  from an root string s_i. Meanwhile, I also need to verify if strings {x_i} are generated from s_i, instead of other root string. Each x_i is fixed length and length of s_i is variable.

How can I achieve this? Look forward to your help.

Comment: I didn’t get the verification part. As far as I can see, given `x_i` and `s_i` there is no way of making sure that `x_i` didn’t come from some other root string.

Comment: Random strings and verifiable if is from root seems impossible to me. Either there is some pattern, so you can evaluate if it comes from the same root, or the strings are random.

Comment: @maraca I beg to differ! See my answer: a seemingly random number, verifiable to come from the root string.

Comment: @MichaelDeardeuff I think you are just concatenating the root and a random string (which might be the best you can get by using a unique delimiter). Otherwise there can be collisions, not only because of the hash. E.g. (A, BCD), (AB, CD), (ABC, D) all give the same string after concatenation. In my opinion concatenating the root and a random string is not really random, even after hashing or encryption.

Comment: @maraca first, yes this can still be improved by including the root length to the hash. Second, a good hash function is indistinguishable from random.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any constraints, so one option is to generate a random string and then append a hash of that and the root string.

For example:

1. Base string (s_i): `FooBar`
2. Random base 64 string (r_i): (`b28DGWIjI5/NeQrw5RBI9KXZ`)
3. `Hash[s_i || r_i]`: = `Hash[FooBarb28DGWIjI5/NeQrw5RBI9KXZ`]
   = `3KGuDze1`
4. Result = `[s_i || Hash]` (x_i): [`b28DGWIjI5/NeQrw5RBI9KXZ || 3KGuDze1`] = `b28DGWIjI5/NeQrw5RBI9KXZ3KGuDze1`

Since the hash is a fixed length, you can pull it off the end to verify if it comes from FooBar:

1. Base string (s_i): `FooBar`
2. Random string: `b28DGWIjI5/NeQrw5RBI9KXZ3KGuDze1` = [`b28DGWIjI5/NeQrw5RBI9KXZ || 3KGuDze1`]
3. assert `Hash[FoorBarb28DGWIjI5/NeQrw5RBI9KXZ]` === `3KGuDze1`

**Note**: In the examples above, I used the first 8 digits of a base64-encoded Sha256 as the hash function.

Here's a first-draft of the system. If it were my system (large distributed system) I'd remove all the string conversion.

```
public class RandomStringGenerator {
    private final int randomLength;
    private final int hashLength;
    private final MessageDigest hasher;

    public RandomStringGenerator(int randomLength, int hashLength, MessageDigest hasher) {
        this.randomLength = randomLength;
        this.hashLength = hashLength;
        this.hasher = hasher;
    }

    public String generate(String base) {
        // the multiplier accounts for the base-64 conversion
        byte[] rand = new byte[randomLength * 3 / 4];
        ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBytes(rand);
        Base64.Encoder base64 = Base64.getEncoder();

        byte[] front = base64.encode(rand);

        hasher.update(base.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        hasher.update(front);

        CharSequence hash = base64.encodeToString(hasher.digest()).subSequence(0, hashLength);

        return new String(front, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + hash;
    }

    public boolean validate(String base, String random) {
        int totalLength = randomLength + hashLength;
        if (random.length() != totalLength)
            return false;

        String front = random.substring(0, randomLength);
        String hash = random.substring(randomLength);

        hasher.update(base.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        hasher.update(front.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        String calculatedHash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hasher.digest());

        return calculatedHash.startsWith(hash);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest hasher = MessageDigest.getInstance("Sha-256");
        RandomStringGenerator gen = new RandomStringGenerator(24, 8, hasher);

        String generated = gen.generate("FooBar");
        System.out.println(generated);

        boolean isValid = gen.validate("FooBar", generated);
        System.out.println("isValid: " + isValid);
    }
}
```